# setting cookie in php - how to retrieve in jquery without a page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, json, cookies

Im storing a JSON in a cookie at a php page (that performs a mysql query) using

```
setcookie("json_cookie", $json, time() + (86400), "/");
```

And retrieving the JSON in a seperate JS page using

```
$.get('star2.php');

$.cookie.json = true;

var json = $.cookie('json_cookie');
```

In order to display the result I have to refresh the page. Is there a way to avoid refreshing?

Comment: Why don't you just have php output the data instead of saving it in a cookie?

Comment: you mean like var json = $.getJSON('star2.php'); ?

Comment: $.getJSON('star2.php', function (response){var json = response});

Comment: thanks but getting an 'undefined is not an object' in the subsequent code